# App Crashing On Startup (Cydia Store)

Tags: ios, xcode, cydia

I built an app for the Cydia store, and followed instructions [here](http://www.sysrage.net/guides/ios-programming/building-and-running-ios-applications-without-a-paid-developer-license).  After signing with ldid, I tested it by uploading to my device using SSH.  It ran just fine. So, I took the same .app file, and uploaded it to thebigboss repository.  It showed up, but after I downloaded it, it crashes on startup every time.  Any thoughts as to the reason?  The app is called Air Home Video

Comment: Could you check the provisioning profile?

Comment: I did not code sign it, per the instructions on the link I posted